# Converting from Python 2 to 3. Sorting With cmp

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I'm trying to update code from Python 2 to Python 3. I know that I have to use `cmp_to_key`. But I am having trouble figuring out how to use it in this context.

The code is in Python 3.7.3.

```
from math import sqrt
from functools import cmp_to_key
```

The function in question

```
def divide_and_conquer(s):
    s.sort(cmp = lambda x,y : cmp(x[0], y[0]))
    cpp = closest_point(s)
    print ("The minimum distance is:")
    print(distance(cpp))
    print(cpp)
```

I get a type error in return, I spent the time to look into to find this but I can't find anything in this context.

Comment: I think in this case you can just use `s.sort(key=lambda x:x[0])`

Comment: how does `s` and `cmp` look like?